# How I can add .bundle file to the repository in GitHub?

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I have GitHub repository and a file of type `.bundle`. How I can merge the `.bundle` file with the GitHub repository assuming that the repository already cloned in my local desktop.

Is these are the right steps that I should follow:

```
git checkout master
git verify ../final.bundle
git fetch ../final.bundle
git log ..FETCH_HEAD
git merge FETCH_HEAD
git push origin master
```

However, the second command is not working, the error is:
`git: 'verfiy' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `git bundle verify ../final.bundle`